# Retain dropdown selection when clicking on back

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have two jsp files,In jsp1 I have a *dropdown* menu.From which I'm passing a value to second jsp. I have a `back` button in my second jsp and when click of that it is coming to first jsp also I have to remember the selection of my dropdown list.I cant achieve the second case.

**First jsp**

```
<select id="ParentType" >
<option value="">select</option>
<%
for(String s:typeList)
{
%>
<option value="<%=s%><%=(s.equals(request.getParameter("value"))?"selected" : "")%> ><%=s%></option>
<%} %>
```

I'm passing a value from my second jsp and I have tried to compare with the option values like above.It is not even showing all the values inside my dropdown also it have a empty selection.

from my **Second jsp**

```
function gt3()
{
var val="<%=selectedType%>";
window.location.assign("gt_Iba?value="+val);
}
```

What I need is when click of back button from jsp2 the selected value should remain same in jsp1. It will be better without the use of storing values in session because it can be used in client side only,but If i'm wrong correct me in this also.Any help before mark this question as **duplicate**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a quote in

```
<option value="<%=s%><%=(s.equals(request.getParameter("value"))?"selected" : "")%> ><%=s%></option>
```

Should be

```
<option value="<%=s%>" <%=(s.equals(request.getParameter("value"))?"selected" : "")%> ><%=s%></option>
```